# Export a dynamic array from a React component to another component

Tags: reactjs, export, components

I built a react component that imports a Json file into an array to map the result. I need that array in another component. I don't know if I must built this component inside the new component or if there's a method to export the needed array (data). The array source is updated every 4 seconds.

Thanks for your help.

My first component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


class Ramas extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const fetchData = () => {
            axios
            .get('http://localhost:8888/dp_8/fuente/procesos_arbol.json')
            .then(({ data })=> {
                this.setState({
                    data: data
                });
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(()=> {console.log('no recibido');});
        };
        fetchData();
        this.update = setInterval(fetchData, 4000);
    } //  final componentDidMount


    render() {
        const initialData = this.state.data.map((el) => {
            return (
        <p>id={ el.id } | name - { el.name } | padre - {el.parent}</p>
      );
        });


        return (<div className="datos_iniciales">
      { initialData }
      </div>);
    }

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Ramas />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Is this working for you? Are you asking if is there a better solution or are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, Rodius. I want reuse that array like data source in another components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one top level component that can contain the two components.

in the Ramas component ->

```
const updatedData = setInterval(fetchData, 4000);
this.props.datasource(updatedData);
```

write a new top level component ->

```
class TopComponent Extends React.Component{
  state = {data: ''}

  handleDataUpdate = (updatedData) => {
     this.setState({data: updatedData});
  }

  render = () => {
      <Ramas datasource={this.handleDataUpdate}>
          <SecondComponent updatedData={this.state.data}>
      </Ramas>
  }

}
```

now from **SecondComponent** *updatedData* prop you can get the fresh data

**By the way it is in ES7 syntax I wrote**

Answer (score 1):

If you have parent component, you should pass function from it to this component as a prop.
That function will than set state and data will flow one way as it's imagined with ReactJS.

For example instead of this.setState, you could call 
this.props.jsonToArray
and in jsonToArray you should call setState which will pass data to that seccond component.